# Linq query to give pivot table kind result

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a class with 4 properties. I want to obtain a pivot table like result from a list of this object by grouping 2 fields and counting 2 other numeric fields. I couldn't manage to do that any help will be appreciated :

```
class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int AccidentCount { get; set; }
    public int MaintenanceCount { get; set; }
}

List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
{
    new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-200", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 0},
    new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-200", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 1},
    new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-200", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 1},
    new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-180", AccidentCount = 0 ,MaintenanceCount = 1},
    new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-180", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 1}
};
```

Query result should be :

- Make Model   AccidentCount   MaintenanceCount
- Mercedes   E-200   3               2
- Mercedes   E-180   1               2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ and group your cars by `Make` and `Model`. Now you can sum up `AccidentCount` and `MaintenanceCount`:

```
IEnumerable<Car> summedUp = cars.GroupBy(c => new { c.Make, c.Model })
    .Select(g => new Car()
        {
            Make = g.Key.Make,
            Model = g.Key.Model,
            AccidentCount = g.Sum(c => c.AccidentCount),
            MaintenanceCount = g.Sum(c => c.MaintenanceCount)
        });
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. And if i want to add "where model is not null" where should i add it in the query?

Comment: Simply add the where before grouping: `cars.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Model)).GroupBy...`

Comment: One more question, if i add a new field like SecondHand to Car Class and want to output this column value in query in one row as only "Y" or "N" depending on the grouping and with a condition that if there is a "Y" in rows for this value only output "Y" (not "Y" and "N" in different rows) and if all rows have "N"s than only in this case "N" how to do that ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Could you edit your question?

Comment: I have asked the question in another topic to make it more clear link to question is  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974007/linq-query-with-grouping-and-conditional-result/43974392#43974392