# linq query with grouping and conditional result

Tags: linq

I have an addition to a similar question I have asked before. I have a list of car type structured like below :

```
class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string SecondHand { get; set; }
        public int AccidentCount { get; set; }
        public int MaintenanceCount { get; set; }
    }

List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
{
new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-200", SecondHand ="N", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 0},
new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-200", SecondHand ="N", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 1},
new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-200", SecondHand ="Y", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 1},
new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-180", SecondHand ="N", AccidentCount = 0 ,MaintenanceCount = 1},
new Car(){Make = "Mercedes", Model = "E-180", SecondHand ="N", AccidentCount = 1 ,MaintenanceCount = 1} 
};
```

What i need in output of query is 2 columns for Make and Model by grouping them, get sum of AccidentCount and MaintenanceCount in 2 columns and finally if there is any "SecondHand" value"Y" for a given Model output "Y" otherwise "N".

Output for above should be :

```
Make      Model  AccidentCount  MaintenanceCount SecondHand  
Mercedes  E-200  3              2                Y 
Mercedes  E-180  1              2                N
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i need in output of query is 2 columns for Make and Model by grouping them,

```
cars.GroupBy(c=> new {c.Make,c.Model})
```

> get sum of AccidentCount and MaintenanceCount in 2 columns

```
AccidentCount = g.Sum(c=>c.AccidentCount),
MaintenanceCount = g.Sum(c=>c.MaintenanceCount)
```

> and finally if there is any "SecondHand" value"Y" for a given Model output "Y" otherwise "N".

```
SecondHand = g.Any(c=> c.SecondHand=="Y") ? "Y" : "N"
```

The final query looks like this:

```
cars.GroupBy(c=> new {c.Make,c.Model})
        .Select(g=> new Car {
              Make = g.Key.Make,
              Model = g.Key.Model, 
              AccidentCount = g.Sum(c=>c.AccidentCount),
              MaintenanceCount = g.Sum(c=>c.MaintenanceCount),
              SecondHand = g.Any(c=> c.SecondHand=="Y") ? "Y" : "N"
              });
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave the result i seek.